# Trouble in Using Quartz with spring webapp - Not able to see errors on cosole

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz within a Spring MVC application.

I have a task class, all functionality and logic is written there. I have a separate quartz configuration file. I am just hitting a URL and in controller function initializing the quartz conf file. The job is running fine. The issue I am facing is:

In my task class, some code is running and from a point of time. I am not getting it to run and I am not able to see any error or exception. Here is the code for my task class.  I am able to run the getValues() function on a timely basis with quartz. The problem is it's printing the value hi and nothing else.  It's not going in if nor else and neither is showing any error or exception.

```
public class TeamUpdateImpl implements TeamUpdate {

    // @Autowired
    ReadXmlDao readXmlDao;

    public void setReadXmlDao(ReadXmlDao readXmlDao) {
        this.readXmlDao = readXmlDao;
    }

    public void getValues() {

        System.out.print("Hi");

        if (readXmlDao.getName().equals("Hema")) {
            System.out.print("if cond");
        } else {
            System.out.print("else cond");
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest a solution, some logging thing or something so that I could get at least errors on my console to fix them.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your log4j configuration? Also, if you're using XML configuration rather than autowiring, could you post your Spring config?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `readXmlDao` or readXmlDao.getName() is null.

Try to print it.

```
System.out.print("readXmlDao = "+readXmlDao);
System.out.print("readXmlDao.getName() = "+readXmlDao.getName());
```

You will get npe on printing readXmlDao.getName() if readXmlDao is null.
Also

Try to set `@Autowired` on setReadXmlDao method.

```
@Autowired
public void setReadXmlDao(ReadXmlDao readXmlDao) {
    this.readXmlDao = readXmlDao;
}
```